# Material-UI: TextField: react-addons-css-transition-group breaks with multiline TextFields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

If a `TextField` with multiline is wrapped in a `react-addons-css-transition-group` it breaks the show transition. Is there any way to handle this properly?

Here's my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-v4byd

If you remove the `multiline` tag the transition work.

EDIT: I've adjusted my code to the answer from Fraction but it still doesn't work: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vpde6

EDIT2: working example for the second demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-1kdyl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the following example, I've used [`react-transition-group`](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/) because the doc from `react-addons-css-transition-group` says:

> The code in this package has moved. We recommend you to use `CSSTransitionGroup` from `react-transition-group` instead.

You could use [`CSSTransition`](http://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/css-transition) instead of `ReactCSSTransitionGroup` for one item or combined with [`TransitionGroup`](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/transition-group) for a list of `CSSTransition` Components :

```
import { CSSTransition } from "react-transition-group";

...

<CSSTransition
  in={this.state.show}
  timeout={400}
  classNames="Test"
  unmountOnExit
>
  {this.renderTextField()}
</CSSTransition>
```

You must remove `if (!this.state.show) { return null; }` from `renderTextField` since `CSSTransition` requires a child.

*test.css* (the `opacity` property is not mandatory)

```
.TestWrapper {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
}

.Test-enter {
  left: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}

.Test-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
  transition: left 400ms, opacity 400ms;
}

.Test-exit {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 0px;
}

.Test-exit-active {
  opacity: 0;
  left: 100px;
  transition: left 400ms, opacity 400ms;
}
```

**Working example**:

[image: Edit Material demo]

Comment: Oh man, I should read the notes instead only the rest of the page, thanks!

Comment: That's crazy. I've adjusted my dev code and it still doesn't work. :( I've created a new CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-vpde6

Comment: There is no problem with the code I've provided. working example for the second demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-1kdyl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: I've got it now: It's important on which position the transition is provided.